# Tab completion is not working for nested divs on sublime text 3

Tags: macos, sublime-text-3, osx-el-capitan, sublime-text

Tab completion is not working for my sublime text 3 on Mac OSX EI Capitan. I've checked my sublime text's settings and it's 
    `”tab_completion": true`
When I type div.container and press tab it becomes

```
 <div class="container"></div>
```

But when I type div.container>div.row and press tab then it becomes

```
div.container><div class="row"></div>
```

I've installed the following packages on my sublime text-

```
emmet, laravel-blade, PHP-Twig, SublimeAllAutocomplete
```

But still now it's not working.

Comment: This is off-topic for [su] but would be a good fit for our sister site [so].

Comment: I found most of this types of questions are asked here. That's why I asked here. Personally I also prefer stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could fix it. I removed the default emmet plugin and clone it again from github to the packages directory. The cloned directory name is different from the default one. And after restarting sublime it's working fine.